# How can convert rows of a table with a drop down list

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, html-table

I am new to PHP. In my site I have this code that is show a table of a product and it's items. I want to convert rows of table with a drop down list.

```
<table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <td class="a-right">
                <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <td class="a-center">
            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Image of above code in site:

[image]

And what I want is :

[image]

I try so much but I can't do this.

Comment: It seems like magento code right?

Comment: @DishaV: yes, It is magento.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want? If you compress products into dropdown then how will you manage price of each product? Would it goes to dropdown too? and what about `Count`?

Comment: @DishaV: Yes, I want items compress into a dropdown list and when each item select the price of that item will show in price.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote some simple code. You can implement it on any Apache or Nginx server. This is the idea. The rest is changing of variable names.

```
<?php
$products = array(
    array('name' => 'eggs', 'quantity' => 10, 'price' => 10),
    array('name' => 'fishes', 'quantity' => 7, 'price' => 8),
    array('name' => 'tires', 'quantity' => 8, 'price' => 15),
    array('name' => 'boats', 'quantity' => 0, 'price' => 30),
    array('name' => 'breads', 'quantity' => 12, 'price' => 6),
);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Effective JavaScript: Frogger</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            table { 
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 60%;
            }
            th {
                width:20%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="4">
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if (is_array($products) && count($products) > 0) {
                        echo '<select id="product_names">';
                        foreach ($products as $product_id => $product) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $product_id . '">' . $product['name'];
                            echo '</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td><span id="product_price"></span></td>
                <td>
                    <input id="needed_quantity" type="number" value="0" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
<?php echo 'var products = ' . json_encode($products) . ';'; ?>
            console.log(products);
            $(document).ready(function() {
                set_price();
                $('#product_names').change(function() {
                    set_price();
                    set_zero_quantity();
                });
                $('#needed_quantity').change(function() {
                    check_needed_quantity();
                });
            });
            function set_price() {
                var prod_id = $('#product_names').val();
                $('#product_price').text(products[prod_id]['price']);
            }
            function check_needed_quantity() {
                var needed_quantity = $('#needed_quantity').val();
                var prod_id = $('#product_names').val();
                var total_quantity = products[prod_id]['quantity'];
                if (needed_quantity > total_quantity) {
                    $('#needed_quantity').val(total_quantity);
                    $('#needed_quantity').css('color', '#0000dd');
                } else {
                    $('#needed_quantity').css('color', 'black');
                }
            }
            function set_zero_quantity() {
                $('#needed_quantity').val(0);
                $('#needed_quantity').css('color', 'black');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Elham Gdz, Add some comment, please!

Comment: First apologize for the delay. I test your code it doesn't show name and price of products and the count be in select however the customer could be enter the number of count and the products should be in select and when customer select one of the product the price of that product should be show in price. (Like the last picture that i uploaded in my question.)

Comment: I have printed only the select with the  products names.

Comment: And one JSON object with all the rest data.

Comment: Can you print the JSON object, please.

Comment: Do you have some test link - where I can see the result?

Comment: It doesn't show item's name, and I work in local, sorry that I can't give you link. I change somethings in your code and now it is show the item's name but instead of show item 1 when page load it is show item 9 in select, why?

Comment: My Skype name is koredalin. If you want - you can find me there.

Comment: can you show me the result of your code in jsfiddle or some where like this?

Comment: Try <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?> for select's text. May be I understood the task wrong.

Comment: Your code in the exercise is not the showed below in the picture. It is some your implementation. I should change something in the php code. I'll do it later. The JS part is the easiest thing of all. You have list of items with there current  quantity. You just check if the user wants some more pieces from product. I'll try to print some sample on my testing server.